# Segfault when accessing non-null pointer?

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, segmentation-fault, queue

The code works fine in a Linux environment, but in Windows it crashes 5-10 seconds after the program starts. The debugger points to `n->fired = true;` as the problem?

```
void ParticleSystem::PrivProcessParticles(pNodePtr n, double frameTime)
{
      while(n != NULL) {
        n->fired = true;
        if(!n->immortal)
            n->life -= frameTime; //Decrement life
        n->particle.ApplyAccel2D(frameTime);

        /* Since the oldest particles will always be on
           top of the queue, if life is zero, dequeue! */
        if(n->life <= 0) {
            if(head != NULL && !n->immortal) {
                pNodePtr curr;
                curr = head;
                head = head->next;
                delete curr;
            }
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Allocation:

```
void ParticleSystem::AddParticle(double lifeIn, double x, double y, double angle,
                                 double size, double force, bool immortalIn)
{
    //Increment particle count
    count++;

    //Allocate
    pNodePtr n = new particleNode;

    //Initialize
    n->particle.CreateQuad(size);
    n->particle.SetTexture(texture);
    n->particle.SetPos2D(x, y);
    n->particle.SetRot2D(angle);
    n->particle.SetTopSpeed(topSpeed);
    n->particle.SetVelocity(force);

    n->life = lifeIn;
    n->immortal=immortalIn;
    n->fired = false;
    n->next = NULL;

    //Place
    if (head == NULL) 
    {
        head = n;
        tail = n;
        n->next = NULL;
    } else {
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}
```

Node:

```
struct particleNode {
        Quad particle;
        double life;
        bool fired;
        bool immortal;
        particleNode* next;
};
```

Comment: Just because it's not null, doesn't mean it's pointing at a valid object.

Comment: How could I verify that the object is the problem?

Comment: Look at the pointer and see if it is something like 0xDEADBABE or the like.  You either are using unitialized, freed with dangling pointer, or possibly corrupted memory for your pointer.

Comment: The pointer seem to be valid, must be corrupted memory? How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information posted. However, here's one potential source of the problem.

When your `PrivProcessParticles` function performs its iterations over `n`, it can decide to delete `head` element of your list. But is it possible that at the moment when it decides to delete `head`, `n` is actually the same as `head`? If so, deleting `head` turns `n` into a dangling pointer, which leads to disastrous consequences at `n = n->next`.

Add `assert(curr != n)` before `delete curr` and see whether that assertion holds or fails.

Anyway, what is the starting value of `n` passed to `PrivProcessParticles` by the caller? Can it by any chance happen to be the same as `head`?

P.S. Also, just out of curiosity, the logic that you use to decide whether to perform the deletion or not seems to suggest that the decision is actually made about node `n` (you check `n->life <= 0` and `n->immortal`). But then you proceed to delete `head`, not `n`... Is that by design?

P.P.S. A nitpick: you are doing excessive `n->next = NULL` initializations in your `AddParticle`.

Comment: Adding assert caused it to fail. Head is being passed to the function.

Comment: The oldest particles, which will be at the start of the list, will be the first to die. Therefore I delete the head and advance the head pointer to the next node in the queue.

Comment: @Graztok: Well, if the assertion fails, then that is your problem right there. You are deleting the data from under `n` and then trying to read the dead memory at `n = n->next`.

Comment: The real problem here is rolling his own linked list instead of just using std::list.